# How to call multiple commands on package.json using MacOS

Tags: node.js, macos, package.json

I'm migrating my project from Windows to MacOS. Here is the script I have in Windows, inside package.json:

```
"start-dev": "nodemon --exec \"set NODE_ENV=development && cd ./src && babel-node server.js",
```

How do I write that under MacOS ? This is what I've tried with no success:

```
"start-dev": "nodemon --exec \"NODE_ENV=development cd ./src babel-node server.js",
```

Using Windows like command I'm getting the following error:

```
$ yarn start-dev
yarn run v1.6.0
(node:6638) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
$ nodemon --exec "set NODE_ENV=development && cd ./src && babel-node server.js
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write the same command under macOs.

```
"start-dev": "nodemon --exec \"set NODE_ENV=development && cd ./src && babel-node server.js",
```

The above commands should work on MacOS. If not please tell us what is the error you get.

EDIT:
You don't close your quotes:
I think you want to do that (added a quote at the end):

```
"start-dev": "nodemon --exec \"set NODE_ENV=development && cd ./src && babel-node server.js\"",
```

Answer (score 0):

give this a try, assuming you are under bash:

```
export NODE_ENV=development && cd src && nohup babel-node server.js &
```